# Can a server identify that I am using a modified user-agent?

Tags: networking, browser, spoofing, user-agent

I have a work laptop A that connects, via Google Chrome, to Google Workspace for access to things such as email, Google Drive, calendar, etc. The current IT policy is to block connections from anything other than laptop A. The laptop connects via a wifi without any VPN.

For various reasons (e.g. laptop A is out of battery and an emergency arises at work) I occasionally need to connect via laptop B. My current idea is to spoof the browser's user-agent on laptop B to match that of laptop A.

My question is whether there is any other way that the server can detect that I am not connecting from laptop A and, if so, what counter-measures I could take.

In case it matters, I have my line manager's approval for this.

Comment: Why do you think it's the user-agent  that's used to identify the connecting computer?

Comment: I would talk to tech support, and ask if laptop B can also be whitelisted, preferably via email with managers approval in it. They are most likely going to just do this for you.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: @Tetsujin If I'm connecting over an arbitrary internet connection, and using the browser to connect, what can it be other than user-agent? It's an assumption on my part, but (I thought) a reasonable one.